# Trying to format numbers to time format from database

Tags: angular, typescript, function

I have some trouble formatting some time formats I receive from my database. I want to convert two types of data from the database to show it on my page in a nice format. For example in my database I got 04:00 as 400 and 18:30 as 1830.
I have this code:

```
formatTime(time) {
    //Atleast3characterslong
    if (time.length > 2) {

      let firstDigits = time.substring(0, time.length - 2);  //lastDigitscharacters
      let lastDigits = time.slice(-2);  //removesthelastDigitschars
      let formattedHour = (firstDigits.length > 1) ? firstDigits + ":" + lastDigits : "0" + firstDigits + ":" + lastDigits;  //Concatenatesthem
      return formattedHour;
    } else if (time.length <= 2) {
      let firstDigits = '00';
      let lastDigits = time;
      let formattedHour = (lastDigits.length < 2) ? firstDigits + ":0" + lastDigits : firstDigits + ":" + lastDigits;
      return formattedHour;
    }
    return time;
  }
```

I expect to show 400 as 04:00, 1830 as 18:30 and so on on my page, I don't know why it's not working, any help?

Comment: The mentioned examples (`400` and `1830`) work as expected:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ayljgb?file=index.js
What did you get as output? Isn't maybe the application cached in your browser?

Comment: yes I see but if I log them on mine its not working, maybe its cached

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a zero in front:

```
formatTime(time) {
  if(time.length !=4){
    time = "0"+time;
  }
  return time.substring(0, 2) + ":" + time.substring(2)
}
```

Maybe you should consider working with datformats and the angular date pipe